# Docker Won't Install Python

Tags: python, docker

I recently started learning docker and I was attempting to build a flask python image by following a tutorial video.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python

CMD echo "Python Installed"

RUN pip install flask

COPY . /opt/source-code

ENTRYPOINT FLASK_APP=/opt/source-code/app.py flask run
```

this is the Dockerfile in my source code working directory, I run `sudo docker build . -t nxte/custom-app` on a digitalocean droplet with docker installed but it returns `The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install python' returned a non-zero code: 1`.

Any suggestions? I have no idea what the problem is since I followed the tutorial to a T.

Comment: Are there any logs from the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `-y` with apt-get:

```
RUN apt-get -y install python
```

Also notice that the above does not install `pip` and it's not
possible to install it with `apt-get -y install python-pip` so either
switch to Python 3 and then `apt-get -y install python3` and `apt-get -y install python3-pip` or get pip from other sources.

Comment: Also, it's better to run all `apt-get` commands in one `RUN` section of Dockerifle to use fewer docker layers(the final image will use less space) https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers